# Is it correct to set up a variable inside a php try-catch?

Tags: php, datetime, try-catch, standards

I know I can. I know it works. But, is it correct? I'm thinking that is like putting a div inside a span: you can but someone will hunt you, find you and destroy you.

```
// $value comes from $_POST no validation
try {
    $value = new DateTime($value);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $value = new DateTime();
}
```

Comment: Could you please past the _real_ code behing your decision? In itself is correct, but if is the right thing to do depends on the situation

Comment: There's no big difference between this and the _real_ code. `$value` comes from `$_POST` without validation, so it could be anything. After the `try-catch` I'm modifying an Entity and persisting it to the database (doctrine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly fine if doing so may result in an exception being thrown. Otherwise you are adding unnecessary overhead to whatever action is being performed.

In your case an exception will be thrown if `$value` is not a valid value. So your try/catch is necessary to catch the exception and react to it accordingly, which you do.